# Gender not matching?

Tags: grammar

Reading and listening to a [bible passage](https://www.bible.com/nl/bible/1197/JER.7.ICL00P), I saw “le stesse azioni vergognose” & “i loro inclinazioni perverse.”  I listened to the audio more than once, and it does sound like they said what is written.  (First one by a female reader and second by a male.)  “le stesse” & “i loro” tells me that “azioni” & “inclinazioni” are nouns and not verbs.

Why does the gender not agree?  Why not “azioni vergognosi” & “inclinazioni perversi”?

Comment: That link has "le stesse azioni abominevoli" (which is fine because "azioni" is the plural of "azione", feminine), but I can't find "inclinazioni" on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked passage uses a different phrasing than the text quoted in the question, but the correct agreements are *le stesse azioni vergognose* and *le loro inclinazioni perverse*. In both case, all words are feminine: *azioni* is feminine (the plural of *azione*), the final *-i* notwithstanding, as is *inclinazione*, *-i* and all other nouns in *-zione*, *-i*.